# Flutter printing invoice to usb printer in desktop app

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, printing, flutter-desktop

I'm working on flutter desktop app and i need to print invoice to USB printer.

https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/printing

Currently i m using this plugin but not working, it only shows pdf view with loading indicator only. not loading the invoice view i created.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_usb_write. This is another plugin i've tried so far but when running the app is shows exception  stated unable to find method implementation for detecting usb connected devices.

Please help me solving this issues or suggest me some another solution or plugin.

Thanx.

Comment: Did you found a solution? I'm with the same problem.

Comment: I used the same plugin to print invoice and didn't show the invoice view on UI. Instead I printed the layout directly to attached printer.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter desktop has been launched as [stable earlier this year](https://medium.com/flutter/announcing-flutter-for-windows-6979d0d01fed). Perhaps you may want to try running a desktop build again using the latest Flutter version. Simply run `flutter upgrade` to update the Flutter version that you're running on. Currently, the [printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) plugin is one of the stable printer plugins on Flutter.

If the issue persists, please include the logs from the app. This should give indicators if the app is able to communicate with the printer or if there's any issues with the document that you're trying to print.